# How can I mount speakers that don't have mount adapters?

Tags: drywall, walls, mounting, speakers

How can I mount a pair of speakers to my apartment walls?  Specifically, how do I mount speakers that have no mounting points?  They are from a turntable set from the 80's most likely before the standard was to include a screw hole or wall mount.  What's the best way to go about this with the least amount of damage done to the speakers and the apartment wall?

For those of you that were wondering

Speaker Dimensions: 7.5 inches deep x 12 inches wide x 23 inches tall

Comment: How heavy are the speakers, and what dimensions? Do you want to mount them flat to the wall, or be able to aim them? Pictures of them or a similar model may help

Comment: How about some small floating shelves like [this](http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/public/9eOgzwIJ1d2t-fl4ZzT7xDOgrsoBmmSo8G3vu7RMRjuXS7qzczPpPunJx_QdSKhZuvFUG_HIFiRx093Teo3A_AuBbr4jXU0EoaTnTaDCEUXXK78fjUOth3gUa3S-R3Zfq-U6RAjXh6g1C5F-w_y2rr_MwOPRhTyGOuWHpi9_j0F9lf2QPjV9cSBVVdLlQQalg4L8eTjwWanHDFf9XDo_sYDbg8Q)?

Comment: I added the dimensions of the speaker.  @gregmac I plan on mounting them flat on the wall.

Comment: Most speakers will sound best if they're not flush against the wall. Particularly if they have a port for bass on the back of the speaker. But maybe a "turntable set from the 80s" is more about style than sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out a home theater/audio site like [Parts Express](http://www.parts-express.com/), you'll find oodles of different ways to wall mount a speaker.

For heavier speakers, I've used [these guys](http://www.parts-express.com/pe/showdetl.cfm?Partnumber=240-710) in the past with excellent results.  I think they're rated for 50lbs each.  Plenty of adjustability and easy installation.  I used heavy-duty drywall anchors to mount mine.

[image]

[image]

Add some [in-wall speaker wire](http://www.parts-express.com/wizards/searchResults.cfm?srchExt=CAT&srchCat=376) and some [wall plates with binding posts](http://www.parts-express.com/pe/showdetl.cfm?Partnumber=261-352), and you've got a nice, clean install.

[image]

Comment: I know the wall plates don't fall under "least amount of damage to the walls", but I got all excited :)

Answer (score 5):

If the speakers are reasonably small, there are small mountings used to hang mirrors and paintings, that you could screw onto the back of the speakers. Something like these:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure you seal the screw holes with some sealant when you are done to prevent air leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Most speaker housings have a lip you could cut a small groove in to make a hanging spot for them. That is if you don't want to spend any money. Otherwise Guffa has it spot on.

Comment: That is a great alternative that I didn't even think about.  I'll have to see if that works.

Comment: yeah I have some picture frames I have hung that way.